# circuit breaker design pattern implementation advice

Tags: design-patterns, circuit-breaker

I'm implementing the circuit breaker design pattern for a large scale distributed system (on AWS).

Netflix gives a great description here: http://techblog.netflix.com/2011/12/making-netflix-api-more-resilient.html

I need some advice for the backend monitoring database implementation. Basically, I need a database/daemon/service that can do the following:

1. Store thousands of writes per second.
2. Quickly sum thousands of records (last few seconds) or otherwise maintain a rolling average calculation of statuses, etc (preferably with some caching).
3. Store two weeks worth of data or the results of the calculations in step 2.

Is there an existing database or other software that's good for this task? I doubt Netflix will give me theirs ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/) at the backend. Check [this article](http://techblog.netflix.com/2011/01/nosql-at-netflix.html) about Netflix architecture...